# VueJS lifecycle after submit form

Tags: forms, d3.js, vuejs3

I would like to plot some d3js chars in vuejs after performing an API call to get some data. To do so, I created a form whose input is used to collect the data from the API. Once I submit the form, I call my d3js function to plot the charts based on the retrieved data. I want the plotting functions to be called only when the data is not empty. To do so, I used the conditional rendering v-if based on the length of the data. So far so good. My problem is that once the plots are rendered if I type anything in the form, a new plot will be created as if every time the if statement is evaluated again and again, I don't know if it is related to lifecycle or not, but how can avoid this behavior?

```
<template>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <h4>Associate Information</h4>
        
          <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
            <input placeholder="Associate Id" v-model="associateId" /> <br />
            <input placeholder="Starting date" v-model="initialDate" /> <br />
            <input placeholder="Ending date" v-model="finalDate" /> <br />
            <button v-on:click="getAssociatesbyIdAndDates()">submit</button>
          </form>
        
  

  <div class="chart" v-if="dailyData.length">
          {{ DailyBillabilityLinePlot() }}
          {{ WeeklyMonthlyQuarterlyBarPlot(weeklyData) }}
  </div>
  
  <div class="linePlot"></div>
  <div class="barPlot" v-if="weeklyData.length">
    
    <button v-on:click="WeeklyMonthlyQuarterlyBarPlot(weeklyData)">Weekly</button>
    <button v-on:click="WeeklyMonthlyQuarterlyBarPlot(monthlyData)">Monthly</button>
    <svg id="chart" viewBox="0 0 960 300"></svg>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3'
export default {
  name: 'Timecard',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },

  data() {
    return {
      apiUrl: "",
      myNumber: 0,
      environment: "",
      apiTst:"",
      name:"",
      initialDate: "",
      finalDate: "",
      associateId: "",
      dailyData: [],
      weeklyData:[],
      monthlyData:[],
    }
  },
methods: {
  WeeklyMonthlyQuarterlyBarPlot(data){
  // plot a d3 bar plot
      
 },
  DailyBillabilityLinePlot() { // plot another d3 line plot}
  getAssociatesbyIdAndDates() {
      // Connect to the backend and get the list of associates
      // http://localhost:8080/timecards/period/test/274/2020-04-14/2020-04-22
      console.log("Fetching the data for an associates from the backend based on initial date and final date...");
      this.axios.get(this.apiUrl + "test/period/test/" + this.associateId + "/" + this.initialDate + "/" + this.finalDate)
        .then(response => {
            this.dailyData = response.data;
            console.log(response.status);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        })

      this.axios.get(this.apiUrl + "test/weekly/" + this.associateId + "/" + this.initialDate + "/" + this.finalDate)
        .then(response => {
            this.weeklyData = response.data;
            console.log(response.status);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        })

      this.axios.get(this.apiUrl + "test/monthly/" + this.associateId + "/" + this.initialDate + "/" + this.finalDate)
        .then(response => {
            this.monthlyData = response.data;
            console.log(response.status);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        })
    },}
  onSubmit() {
      let consultantApi = {
       name: this.name,
       initialDate: this.initialDate,
       finalDate: this.finalDate,
     }
     this.$emit('consultantApi-submitted', consultantApi)

     this.name = ''
     this.initialDate = ''
     this.finalDate = ''
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.apiUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND_API;
    this.environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  }
```

Initial Form
[image: Initial Form]

D3 plots after submitting the completed form
[image: D3 plots after submitting the completed form]

Creation of new d3 plots whenever I press any key in the form
[image: Creation of new d3 plots whenever I press any key in the form]

Comment: Do you need the form to stay visible after submission so the user can enter new info? Or can the form just disappear after submission?

Comment: That would be an option, but I would prefer if the user could create a new submission to see the billability for other dates.

Comment: Could you show the code where weeklyData is set?

Comment: done, it's in getAssociatesbyIdAndDates()

Comment: Your plotGroup element is created each time you call update(). Create it once and update its contents in update()

Comment: actually, the update is called when the button "<button v-on:click="WeeklyMonthlyQuarterlyBarPlot(weeklyData)">Weekly</button>" is clicked, this works fine actually. Maybe it wasn't a good idea to show the plot function. The problem is that after the plots are created, whatever keyboard I press in the form, will add a new plot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is because updating any model will re-render the entire component.

To get around it, I find the simplest way is to put the chart into another component so that the re-render is then guarded.

### Example:

```js
var app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      abc: 'ABC',
      list: [1, 2, 3]
    };
  }
});

app.component("my-chart", {
  template: `<div >{{Math.random()}}</div>`
});

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.6/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="abc" />
  <div v-if="list.length">
    {{Math.random()}}
  </div>
  <my-chart></my-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, I am not sure to understand what you want to show me. Each time I add or remove a letter from the form, a new random value is generated. This is exactly what I want to avoid. I would like a value to be generated only when the submit button is clicked. Do you think you could update your example? Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Comment: There are two numbers, the top one is part of the same component as the data and changes with the input, the second is inside another component, and doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

I think your bug is in the parent component. I would try to check how often does it emmit the consultantApi. It seems like your form keeps submitting on input change event and not on form submit.